# How can I restore Matrix content after accidentally changing its field type?

Tags: assets, matrix

We accidentally deleted all our body text on all our pages, how do I redo my website to a older version. (24 hours ago)
We changed matrix to assets and after that every body text disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

As John mentioned, restoring a database backup is your best bet.

If you don’t have a recent backup, you may still be able to get your Matrix content back, thanks to semi-bug where Craft doesn’t actually delete Matrix block content, when a Matrix field is converted to something else.

Here’s what you can try:

1. [Enable the Project Config file](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/project-config.html#enabling-the-project-config-file) for your site, if you don’t already have it enabled.
2. Figure out what your field’s `uid` is by looking up its row in your database’s `fields` table.
3. Find the most recent project config backup in `storage/config-backups/` where your field was still a Matrix field. The most recent backup will be called `project.yaml`, the second most recent will be called `project.yaml.1`, and so on. For each file, search for `<field-uid>:` (replace `<field-uid>` with the UID from step 2). If the nested `type` property is set to `craft\fields\Matrix`, you’ve found the right file. It will look something like this:

```
8823155c-e84a-4a38-af30-2cb88b705e7b:
  name: Body
  handle: body
  instructions: ''
  searchable: true
  translationMethod: none
  translationKeyFormat: null
  type: craft\fields\Matrix
  settings:
    maxBlocks: '3'
    localizeBlocks: false
    contentTable: '{{%matrixcontent_testimonials}}'
  fieldGroup: d58a1faa-0bf6-46b2-b880-b0c14bebca75
  contentColumnType: string
```

4. Find the same field definition in your current `config/project.yaml` file, and replace it with the field definition from the backup you found in step 3.
5. As a sanity check, you may want to compare the config backup from step 3 with the subsequent backup (so if you found your matrix field in `project.yaml.10`, compare it with `project.yaml.9`), using a diff tool like FileMerge (comes with macOS) or [Kaleidoscope](https://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com). If there are any other significant changes that happened at the same time, you may want to revert those changes as well in `config/project.yaml`.
6. Now access your Control Panel and click the button to sync your new `project.yaml` changes. When that’s done, if all goes well, your field should be a Matrix field again, and your content will be restored.

Answer (score 1):

Restore your database from a recent backup is your only real option tbh.

Answer (score 1):

`'allowAdminChanges' => false` on your production server is also a tip I can give you.